# Detect left/right arrow click - Desktop App Windows 8.1

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am facing a problem , i want to change data inside listview on left/right arrow click. I added Key_Up and Key_Down event to page but neither is called when i push buttons (it seems to me that those events only work with input type fields).

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is more complicated than you probably anticipate. The key events on a single control are simply not sufficient to get you the data you want in a reliable manner. Instead, you need to handle the Accelerator Key Activated event on the Core Dispatcher.

To accomplish this, you can start by looking at my KeyboardHelper service just so you can see how to handle the basics of the keyboard. But the helper doesn't have anything to handle the arrow keys. If you want to handle arrow keys you will need to add some custom logic.

> > KeyboardHelper class http://xaml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MVA/201410_UniversalApp/Dispatchr.Client/Dispatchr.Client.Shared/Services/KeyboardService/KeyboardHelper.cs

You should notice that VirtualKey.Left and VirtualKey.Right are explicit in the VirtualKeys enumeration. This means checking for them should be a synch. I think this should be all you need to get this working. Feel free to copy any of the code you can use from that class.

Best of luck!

Comment: Yeah it works like a charm :) I just use events to do what i want on left or right arrow

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. But how to use this from another page when a User presses Left key? Please explain with some code